# Is it permitted to lick the adhesive on an envelope?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

While most stamps are now self-adhesive, most envelopes still require moistening the adhesive in order to seal it.  Is it a kashrus problem to lick the envelope's adhesive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [dinonline](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/12/13/licking-stamps/) there is no Kashrus concern with licking an envelope.

Per [Halacha Berura - Rabbi Belsky - Page 3](http://nergavriel.org/uploads/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/HB0602%20-%20consumer%20modern%20world%202.pdf) there is no concern during the year, however on Pesach one should be stringent since the paste may contain wheat starch.

Comment: Why should wheat starch matter? If it isn't food, then it isn't food.

Comment: @GershonGold, then why does its food status not matter the rest of the year?

Comment: @SethJ If you look at the link it explains that there is no Tarfus, however there is a wheat starch

Comment: So he's saying it is food all year, just it is usually made of  kosher ingredients. That's pretty strange, as your first link says, because the taste is clearly pagum, nor are you trying to eat it.

Comment: The first link disagrees with the reasoning of the second link, however they both agree that it is allowed during the year. They disagree regarding Pesach.

Comment: @GershonGold, is he assuring then that it is impossible to purchase Treif envelopes?  That the ingredients and processing are inherently Kosher?  I find that strange.  How can this be assured without supervision?  Does it all come from one plant whose processes have been observed?

Comment: I also don't understand this quote: "On Pesach, however, one should be stringent in this regard and wet [envelopes and stamps] in a different manner, since many pastes contain wheat starch which is chometz." Isn't wetting them also Assur then, not just licking them?

Comment: @SethJ You mean because they will become Chametz and you will own it? I would assume that they became wet previously as part of processing so the real question is not can you wet them on Pesach, but can you own envelopes on Pesach. The answer would seem to be yes because dogs don't eat envelope paste. _Perhaps_ eating it is worse because of [Achshevei](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15075/759) but I don't think anyone is actually trying to make it food when they lick it.

Comment: @SethJ You like my hat? I should go and answer some [tag:sorcery-magic-kishuf] questions while I still have this power.

Comment: If the glue is chameitz when you lick it, why isn't it chameitz before?

Comment: @DoubleAA, ROFL. I concur that we need to open some Purim Torah about hats, but I think we should be self-disciplined and wait for the appropriate month. It's not too far off.  Maybe we can open it a little early so as to keep the hats fresh in our memories.